# SendInput seems not work when focusing on a "Not Responding" window

Tags: windows, mouse, rdp

```
void MouseWin32::Move(float x, float y) {
  INPUT input;
  ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(input));
  input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
  input.mi.mouseData = 0;

  input.mi.dx = x * 65535.0f;   // x being coord in pixels
  input.mi.dy = y * 65535.0f;   // y being coord in pixels

  input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE | MOUSEEVENTF_VIRTUALDESK;

  RTC_LOG(LS_INFO) << "whdebug mouse move input, dx: " << input.mi.dx << " , dy: " << input.mi.dy
                   << ", dwFlags: " << input.mi.dwFlags;

  int ret = SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
  if (ret == 0) {
    int32_t errorcode = (int32_t) GetLastError();
    RTC_LOG(LS_ERROR) << "mousemove failed, err: " << errorcode;
  }
}

void MouseWin32::Click(int action_bit) {
  INPUT input = {0};
  input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
  input.mi.dwFlags = action_bit;

  int ret = SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
  if (ret == 0) {
    int32_t errorcode = (int32_t) GetLastError();
    RTC_LOG(LS_ERROR) << "mouseclick failed, err: " << errorcode;
  }
}
```

Here are my code about mouse move/click.
Everything work fine in normal way.
It seems not work while I foucusing a "not responding" window.

success way:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0faQL.jpg)

fail way:
After focusing the window "not responding"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOmMM.jpg)
mouse move/click seems not react any more...

Is there any strategy in Windows that cannot simulate mouse/keyboard input if user focusing on a "not responding" window?

BTW it's ok by using windows RDP client to the remote server.